# How do I show only 1 scaled image in fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I want to upload 2 scaled images and I do not want to upload the original image. To do this, I set sendOriginal to false. If I set hideScaled to true, no files show in the uploader. If set set hideScaled to false, both scaled images show up in the list. I realize that the [documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html) says not to use both options this way. Is there another way to achieve what I want? How do I make fineuploader show only 1 file on the file list no matter how many scaled images it has?

Comment: It looks like the standard Fine Uploader options do not support a configuration that you wish to implement. Could you perhaps attempt to perform your own element hiding on one of the scaled images within your file list? Perhaps by querying for a known selector on that particular item?

Comment: Is there any way you can add this in a future version? Instead of having a hideScaled attribute, can you add a hide attribute for each size instead?

Comment: I don't know if there has been much demand for this functionality, though I can understand why you would want to essentially make it appear to end users that only one image has been uploaded. Feel free to submit a new [feature request](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/new), which the team can then further investigate.

In the meantime, I still think you could implement this with your own CSS/JS outside of Fine Uploader.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have created a new [feature request](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1505) for this. I can't really understand why I would want to either show all scaled images or not show any at all, so I am not sure why there is no demand for this. Hopefully this feature will be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem.  I also wanted to rename the larger scale to match the original filename and to pass a custom parameter so the server script could sort the images into the db based on scale size.

I used this method as a hackish substitute for an onScaled event.  If anyone is still interested.

```
// Must be onSubmitted, not onSubmit or the DOM element won't be rendered yet.
onSubmitted : function(id, name) {

    // scaling.sizes.name = 'thumb'
    if (name.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(' (thumb).jpg') !== -1) {

        // Hide the element displaying the thumbnail.
        qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).hide();

        // Good place to include any custom parameters based on scale size.
        this.setParams({gpsize : 'thumb'}, id);
    }

    // scaling.sizes.name = 'large'
    else if (name.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(' (large).jpg') !== -1) {

        this.setParams({gpsize : 'large'}, id);

        // If needed rename file in this event, not before, since filename
        // is the hackish hook needed to connect scale size to file id.
        var newName = name.slice(0, name.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(' (large).jpg')) + '.jpg';
        this.setName(id, newName);
    }
    return true;
}
```

It's not perfect, but it gets the job done without bushwhacking through the script files.